# A shorter notation for language of set theory?

Tags: reference-request, notation, terminology

The following is a notation that I want to introduce to shorten writing of formulas in set theory, that idea is to use lower cases to indicate membership in upper case form of them, also use special abbreviation of the subset relation.

Formal Exposition:

Define: $\mathcal Q x(\phi(x)) \iff \mathcal Q x \in X (\phi(x))$

Define $\mathcal Q x'(\phi(x')) \iff \mathcal Q x' \not \in X (\phi(x'))$

Define: $[\mathcal Q x (\phi(x)) \ \texttt{-"-}] \iff [\mathcal Q x (\phi(x)) \land \mathcal Q x' (\neg\phi(x'))]$

Define: $\mathcal Q A^- \equiv_{df} \mathcal Q A^- \subseteq A$

Define: $A^- \subseteq A \iff \forall a^- (a^- \in A)$

Or can be written concealing $``\in"$ as:

$A^- \subseteq A \iff \forall a^- (
\exists a (a^- = a))$

Where $\mathcal Q$ is either $\forall$ or $\exists$ symbols.

Where $\phi(x')$ is the formula obtained from formula $\phi(x)$ by merely replacing all occurrences of the symbol $x$ in $\phi(x)$ by the symbol $x'$, and keeping all other symbols.

So lower case is used to signify membership, so a well formed formula that contains a symbol in lower case must contain its upper case form appearing somewhere in the formula *before* all of occurrences of the lower case form, while symbols written in upper case face no restrictions (a part form the above), so they can even be written alone (not followed by a lower case form of them).

Example: writing axioms of ZFC as:

**Extensionality:** $\forall X,Y ([\forall x (x \in Y) \ \texttt{-"-} ] \to X=Y)$

**Empty:**$\exists X \forall x (x\neq x)$

**Pairing:** $\forall A,B \exists X [\forall x (x=A \lor x=B) \ \texttt{-"-}]$

**Boolean Union:**$\forall A,B \exists X [\forall x (x \in A \lor x \in B) \ \texttt{-"-}]$

**Set Union:** $\forall A \exists X [\forall x (\exists a (x \in a)  ) \ \texttt{-"-}] $

**Power:**$\forall A \exists X [\forall x (\exists A^- (x=A^-)) \ \texttt{-"-}]$

**Separation:** $\forall A \exists X [\forall x ( x \in A \land \phi(x)) \ \texttt{-"-}]$

**Replacement:** $\forall A ( \forall a \exists! S (\phi(a,S))\to\exists X [\forall x (\exists a (\phi(a,x))) \ \texttt{-"-}])$

With the use of *identity* we can conceal the symbol $\in$ altogether, examples are:

**Extensionality:**$\forall X,Y ([\forall x (\exists y (x=y))\ \texttt{-"-}  ] \to X=Y)$

**Boolean Union:**$\forall A,B \exists X [\forall x (\exists a (x = a) \lor \exists b (x=b)) \ \texttt{-"-}]$

**Set Union:** $\forall A \exists X [\forall x (\exists a \exists B (a=B \land \exists b ( x=b))  ) \ \texttt{-"-}] $

**Separation:** $\forall A \exists X [\forall x (\exists a (x=a \land \phi(x))) \ \texttt{-"-}]$

However this is longer, but it gives the pseudo-appearance of set theory written in first order logic with identity!?

> Question: had that been done before?
>
> Question: is it found elegant?

Comment: From the point of view of someone who reads maths sometimes: set theory is hard enough to read as it is; please don't abbreviate it further :P

Comment: @PatrickStevens, Thanks for the comment. From the point view of someone who reads set theory, set theory is not hard to read, and many times we need to shorten formulation, at least its economic in writing. Not only that. This kind of formulation let you concentrate on the core issue of a formula, it lessen repetitions present in the usual notion.

Comment: frtntly u cn do th sm n nglsh nd thrby mk th txt mch esr t rd

Comment: @PatrickStevens, hmm... "fortunately you can do the same in English and thereby make the text much easier to read", I don't see where your short-hand managed to concentrate on the core issue of the above sentence. The original sentence doesn't suffer from undue repetitions, as far as I can see. And English unlike logic is very widely presented through different styles, while logic is pretty much fixed and you have high repetitions in it. So the matter is not the same.

Comment: @PatrickStevens, you removed the vowels, the problem is that with English you have many vowel sounds, that's why its difficult to be done. In Arabic for example, it is usually better readable without short vowels written! because there are just few vowel sounds in Arabic. Here we have only omitted ONE symbol that is $\in$ and not completely so! So it should be readable.